# RadPHP XE как средство разработки

Tags: php

Подскажите, у кого есть опыт использования RadPHP XE, можно ли использовать его для создания Web-приложений?
Речь не только о сайтах, а, в первую очередь, платформонезависимых системах.

Требуется создать простую систему документооборота, вот и решил, а почему бы не реализовать задачу с такими требованиями:

- ОС Win - *nix
- DB MySQL
- GUI - браузер

Тем более, RadPHP так напоминает Delphi.